# Getting a directory?

Tags: java, swing, audio, directory

I have been designing a program that loads a sound-file and then plays it when a button is pressed.

There's a button in the top-left that says "load...", one in the top right that says "clear",
and there are four buttons that are numbered.

Pressing  and then a number-button brings up a window, similar to what you would see when pressing "load" on any other program. I need a code that assigns the selected directory to a string, so that it can be called up when playing the sound in the program. Any suggestions?

EDIT - I have implemented someone's suggestion - Here's what I have done.

```
package soundboard;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Soundboard {

JButton loadButton;
JFileChooser Loader;
JButton clearButton;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JButton button4;
JPanel mainsPanel;

int load;
File one;
File two;
File three;
File four;


public void windowCreate() {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    mainsPanel = new JPanel();

    Loader = new JFileChooser();//174
    Loader.setSize(500,500);
    Loader.setLocation(174,4);


    loadButton = new JButton("Load...");
    loadButton.setSize(80, 30);
    loadButton.setLocation(4, 4);
    loadButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        load = 1;
    });

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setSize(80, 30);
    clearButton.setLocation(92, 4);
    clearButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.println("Cleared");
    });


    button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.setSize(80, 80);
    button1.setLocation(4, 45);
    button1.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            one = Loader.getSelectedFile();
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
        System.out.println(one);
        }
    });

    button2 = new JButton("2");
    button2.setSize(80, 80);
    button2.setLocation(92, 45);
    button2.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            System.out.println("Load 2");
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("2");
        }
    });

    button3 = new JButton("3");
    button3.setSize(80, 80);
    button3.setLocation(4, 133);
    button3.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            System.out.println("Load 3");
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("3");
        }
    });

    button4 = new JButton("4");
    button4.setSize(80, 80);
    button4.setLocation(92, 133);
    button4.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            System.out.println("Load 4");
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("4");
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(loadButton);
    frame.add(clearButton);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    frame.add(button4);
    frame.add(Loader);
    frame.add(mainsPanel);

    frame.setSize(675,485);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Soundboard window = new Soundboard();
    window.windowCreate();

}


}
```

I have only implemented code on button1 however - not 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: If you're using [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), you might want to use [`getCurrentDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getCurrentDirectory--). It will return the selected directory in a `String`.

Comment: You will get more meaningful responses after posting some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `JFileChooser` to select only directories, you can call `setFileSelectionMode` along with `DIRECTORIES_ONLY`:

```
Loader.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Then, as the action listener of the buttons, show the dialog and get the directory:

```
if (Loader.showOpenDialog(mainsPanel) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
    String dir = Loader.getCurrentDirectory();
}
else { /* No selection */ }
```

The Java Tutorials have a chapter on [How to use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) that might be useful.